# Contact 7 Form Wordpress how to get data from a custom HTML Tag (td)?

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

i added to the contact 7 form a table like this:

```
<tr><td><b>Quadratmeter:</b></td><td id="quadrat">[text quadrat id:quadrat]</td></tr><td colspan="2" style="padding-top:6px"></tbody></table>
```

The value from the td element with the id quadrat is set automatically with a javascript function. I need the value for the sending mail now. I have think to add the tag [text quadrat id:quadrat] and use the [quadrat] tag for the mail, but its empty :/

Anyone an idea how i can get the data in the email template ?

Answer (score 0):

You already have the value of #quadrat content in a js variable, then you must pase such value inside your form input using the id.

Using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if(typeof(yourVar) != "undefined"){
        $('#yourEmailIinputId').val(yourVar);
    }       
});
```

Comment: dont know what you mean, how can i get that into the email template from contact 7 without a javascript function ? some way with tags or something like that ?

Comment: Sorry, now I see what you need is to add this email value in the message body of the email notification, not you? In this case, a simple solution is to create a hidden (with css) form input, and then fill it with my script. Tell me if I'm right...

Comment: hi, okay thats one way i see, but can we do it without javascript and only with the syntax from contact form 7 ? the td field from my table is filled with a javascript function, now i need that value (with syntax from c7 plugin) in the mail body section from the contact 7 form.